# MYSQL: West European Characters get Mangled using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

When I run this at the MySQL command line, it works fine:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES(NULL,101942,'2015-05-08','sähkötupakalle');
```

The 'ä' and the 'ö' end up in the MySQL varchar column just fine.

However, when I put the same data in a file, and use

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
```

then the 'ä' and the 'ö' get mangled, and I end up with data in the MySQL varchar column that looks like this:

```
sÃ¤hkÃ¶tupakalle
```

Any ideas for how I can get these characters to load correctly using "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" ??  FYI, my table has CHARSET=utf8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the file you are loading is correctly encoded with utf8?  But you did not include the `CHARACTER SET utf8` clause?

**Symptom of "Mojibake":**
When `SELECTing` the text, each non-english character is replaced by 2-3 characters that you could call jibberish or garbage.

**How you got in the mess:**

- The client's bytes to be `INSERTed` into the table were encoded as utf8 (good), and
- The charset for the connection was `latin1` (eg, via `SET NAMES latin1`), and
- The table column was declared `CHARACTER SET latin1`

**How to fix the text and the table:**

Do the 2-step `ALTER`:

```
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARBINARY(...) ...;
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(...) ... CHARACTER SET utf8 ...;
```

where the lengths are big enough and the other "..." have whatever else (`NOT NULL`, etc) was already on the column.

That converts the column definition while leaving the bits alone.

**How to fix the code (in general):**

- Change the client's declaration of charset to `utf8` - via `SET NAMES utf8` or equivalent.