# How to know which characterset is in text field in MySql database if I know only that text

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

Problem begin when they change php ver from 5.3 to (5.4., 5.5, 5.6)

I have in table text like this :

```
$rus3="Ð’Ñ‹ Ð½Ðµ Ñ…Ð²Ð°Ñ‚Ð°ÐµÑ‚ Ð¿ÑƒÑ‚ÐµÐ²Ð¾Ðº. Ð”Ð¾Ð¿Ð»Ð°Ñ‡Ð¸Ð²Ð°ÐµÑ‚ÑÑ. ÐÐ°Ð¶Ð¼Ð¸Ñ‚Ðµ OK Ð¸ Ð²Ñ‹Ð±ÐµÑ€Ð¸Ñ‚Ðµ Ð½ÑƒÐ¶Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹ Ð¿Ð°ÐºÐµÑ‚ ...";
```

I have the need to convert lots of text in readable table under utf8

Then I use:

```
$rust3=iconv("UTF-8","windows-1252//IGNORE",$rus3);
```

And this is on russian Cyrilic like this:

rust3:
 Вы не хватает путевок. Доплачивает��. �ажмите OK и выберите нужный пакет ...

But not all characters are transform , and some characters not well convert with this parameters of function iconv . I also have more 4 language with special characters deppending of language in database fields, whot I must convert that be visible and legible .

How I can know in which character set are text, if have only that text ( simbols ) and how is the best way to convert it in utf8. When I get from sql command in mysql database character set it show that is already in utf8.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130484/mysql-west-european-characters-get-mangled-using-load-data-local-infile/30134156#30134156

Comment: There's no general answer. You cannot cleanly detect what is what automatically. You've screwed up encodings and you've mangled some bytes in some undefined way. There may not even be any way to repair the data at all, if some data was discarded in the process of mangling it. You have to figure out on a case by case basis what's what and how you may be able to reverse your chain of missteps.

Comment: Start here: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
$str = "bla bla bla";
echo mb_detect_encoding($str);
```

will give you char set

How ever to check charset of mysql db you can use

```
mysql_client_encoding($conn);
```

so as per your question can you try

`echo mb_convert_encoding($rus3, "UTF8", "auto");`
 instead iconv. If that helps check more about mb_convert_encoding

Comment: Thank You but hmm, I realy don't undarstand this. When I execute function mb_detect_encoding($rus3)  result is UTF-8. After conversion function $rust3=iconv("UTF-8","windows-1252//IGNORE",$rus3); and mb_detect_encoding($rust3) , result is again "UTF-8" . Function mysql_client_encoding($conn) give result "utf8" . How diferent chars can have same character code ?

Comment: I feel conversion function is not working properly have you tried echo your string as echo $rust3; and compare it with $rus3. can you see any difference between them ?

Comment: Thank You for bouth. Seems to be in some way to work through. I use $rust3=mb_convert_encoding($rus3,"windows-1252","auto");
$rus3="ruski3-original ___________: Ð’Ñ‹ Ð½Ðµ Ñ…Ð²Ð°Ñ‚Ð°ÐµÑ‚ Ð¿ÑƒÑ‚ÐµÐ²Ð¾Ðº. Ð”Ð¾Ð¿Ð»Ð°Ñ‡Ð¸Ð²Ð°ÐµÑ‚ÑÑ. ÐÐ°Ð¶Ð¼Ð¸Ñ‚Ðµ OK Ð¸ Ð²Ñ‹Ð±ÐµÑ€Ð¸Ñ‚Ðµ Ð½ÑƒÐ¶Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹ Ð¿Ð°ÐºÐµÑ‚ ...";
and
echo $rust3;
"Вы не хватает путевок. Доплачивается. Нажмите OK и выберите нужный пакет ..."
and others:
mb_detect_encoding(rus3) original: UTF-8
mb_detect_encoding(rust3) after conversion: UTF-8
bazaencoding(mysql_client_encoding(link): utf8
also workgood for other languages (croatia,spanish,deutsch)

Comment: I only not undersand if evrything is in utf-8 why show good (visible and legible) when use $rust3=mb_convert_encoding($rus3,**"windows-1252"**,"auto");

Comment: can you edit your question and update the latest one so that it could be readable ?

Comment: I wrote that everything was fine when I use function like this : $rust3=mb_convert_encoding($rus3,"windows-1252","auto");